# Validate Client Application With Custom AuthorizeFilter ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, identity

I am able to validate all requests with

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new Results.ClientAppAuthorization());
```

Except code below

```
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true

        };
```

I want to be able to validate the client app with `[ClientAppAuthorization]` before proceeding to request for Token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should customize `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and override `ValidateClientAuthentication` and then use it on `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` in `Startup` like this:

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            //here Implement your Custom validation
            // check your validation conditions and if true call
            context.Validated();
            // and at end 
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

and then use this in startup

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),

            //change here
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            //hange above line

            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true

        };
```